Preventing Theme Change of Components in Shadcn UI when Switching to Dark Mode using Next.js
I'm currently working on a project using Shadcn UI for my components and Next.js for theming, utilizing next-themes. However, I've encountered an issue when switching to dark mode. By default, when I switch to dark mode, the component themes also change to light, which is not the behavior I desire. Instead, I want the component theme to remain consistent, for example, if I've selected an orange theme for my components, even in dark mode, the components should maintain their orange theme while only the background changes to dark.
How can I achieve this functionality? Is there a way to prevent the automatic theme change of components when switching to dark mode while using Shadcn UI and Next.js for theming? this is my Layout.tsx file
<ThemeProvider attribute="class"  themes={["orange","light","dark","rose"]} defaultTheme="dark" enableSystem>
 <div className="flex h-screen">
  <div className="flex-1">
    <Navbar />
    <main className="md:p-20 p-10 ">{children}</main>
  </div>
</div>
</ThemeProvider>

